# Probability question - seems simple but is not in my opinion?

Tags: probability

If i have 5 universities I am applying to and I have a 10% chance of getting into each university. What is my overall probability into getting into uni at all. They are all independent however I can get accepted at more than one or none so it's quite confusing for me to work it out.

Comment: It is easier to figure out the probability you don't get into any, and subtract that from 1.

Comment: Why do you think being accepted by different universities are independent events? This seems like a very strong and not very likely assumption.

Comment: @Henning, perhaps he only applies to universities whose admission procedures are based on flipping coins.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better grasp at it, since those event are independant, you can treat them as a succession of event :

We not $P_n(success)$ the chance of entering at least one university of $n$ applications.

First university you have 10% chance of entering, $P_1(success) = 0.1$

If you didn't enter the first university, you check the second, which is 10% too. But you only have to check the second university in in case you failed the first one (in $90\%$ of the cases) so $P_2(success) = P_1(success) + 0.9*0.1$

Can you find the equation for $P_n(success)$ ?